# DataContract namespace not showing up properly in WSDL/XSD

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I've Google'd the crap out of this and I'm at the end of my rope. I have a Service Contract defined like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://myfirstnamespace.mycompany.com")]
public interface IMyServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    myServiceResponse MyOperation(myServiceRequest myServiceRequest);
}
```

For my request definition, I have this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://mysecondnamespace.mycompany.com")]
public partial class myServiceRequest
{
    private string field1Field;
    private string field2Field;

    [DataMember]
    public string field1 {
        get {
            return this.field1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field1Field = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string field2 {
        get {
            return this.field2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field2Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the difference in namespaces. Unfortunately the actual code is under lockdown on another computer so I can only do my best to demonstrate the problem. It seems like the Namespace on the DataContract is ignored. My WCF Test Client will generate a sample request much like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.openuri.org/</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <MyOperation xmlns="http://myfirstnamespace.mycompany.com/">
      <myServiceRequest xmlns:d4p1="http://mysecondnamespace.mycompany.com">
        <d4p1:field1 />
        <d4p1:field2 />
      </myServiceRequest>
    </MyOperation>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please note that myServiceRequest is under http://myfirstnamespace.mycompany.com when I specified http://mysecondnamespace.mycompany.com in the DataContract attribute. Why? How can I get this parameter to show up in the Namespace that I want?

I'd also like to note that I have to develop this service to an existing client specification. It's a replacement for a service that is soon-to-be obsolete, so I cannot change the client to accept anything different.

Comment: +1 For a great opening sentence!